# yii ajaxLink is not passing variable to controller

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am trying to pass a variable from an ajaxLink into my controller but my controller is not getting the variable.

//view

```
$ids = Yii::app()->storedData->getIds();
    foreach($ids as $id) {
    echo 'ID '.$id .'<br />';

    echo CHtml::ajaxLink(   
     'remove',                                    
     array('/storedInfo/remove'), 
     array(
      'data' => array('removeItem' => $id),
    ));
    }
```

//controller

```
public function actionRemove() {
        var_dump($_GET['removeItem']);  // RETURNS string(0) ""
        die();
    }
```

Comment: When you view source, what's the generated javascript code show?  Is the value of `$id` there as expected?  Is there any data at all in $_GET?

Comment: do check the accessRules also.

Comment: @ernie Thanks for the reminder...no nothing is showing in view source when trying to capture the variable.  But if I use `array('removeItem' => '100')`, then yes I see 100 and everything works.  I have even tried variable referencing but that does not change anything.  Yet I can just echo $id and get what I need on that page but I really need to send it back to the controller through the link like I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm assuming when you output the ID and `$id`, that's working as expected?  What's `$id`'s data type?  You could be encountering issues when the AJAX is generated via [CJavaScript::encode](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJavaScript#encode-detail). Maybe $id is an object of some sort, so doesn't get a string representation?  Or you could be hitting the final else condition, and getting an empty string ('').  If $id has a __tosString method, then the echo statement could work, but passing it to the javascript encode could fail.

Comment: Yes I can output $id just as expected on that view and as mentioned even variable referencing works.  The data type is smallint.  I have not created any __toString method.

Comment: smallint is the database type, what's PHP report if you do a `gettype($id)`?

Comment: so what's a `var_dump $id` show?  Basically, instead of passing the object, you'll want to use an int or string value

Comment: Thats it ernie, I used settype to change it to a string and now the variable passes.  Thanks for the help.  If you want to put that in a simple answer I will give you the credit.

Comment: Glad I could help . . . that was an interesting question that took a bit of research and I learned a bit about yii along the way. Answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax array you're passing to [CHtml::ajaxLink](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail) ends up taking the whole array and passing it to [CJavaScript::encode()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJavaScript#encode-detail).

As you mentioned in your comments, the `$id` you were using to build your data array was a PHP object.  When this got to CJavaScript::encode, things got wonky, and the results weren't what you were expecting.  Extracting a string or numeric value from $id, rather that passing the whole object should take care of this, e.g.:

```
  'data' => array('removeItem' => $id->value) // obviously you'll need to use the proper key to get the value
```

Or maybe something like this depending on the data structure:

```
  'data' => array('removeItem' => settype($id, 'string'),
```

Answer (score 0):

**I edited out my answer because i admit it was not what the original asker wanted but for the sake of the comments, i leave my code here**

```
    $ids = Yii::app()->storedData->getIds();
    foreach($ids as $id) {
        echo 'ID '.$id .'<br />';

        echo CHtml::ajaxLink(   
           'remove',                                    
            array('/storedInfo/remove', array('removeItem' => $id)), 
        );
    }
```

Comment: where do you see i pass a 3rd option ?

Comment: the second array is in the first, so it will be the parameters for createUrl, not for $ajaxOptions, i dont know how i can explain you to read code, but there is really only 2 parameters for the CHtml::ajaxLink call, have you ever heard of multi dimensional arrays ?

Comment: @ernie : the second paramter builds the url with [normalizeUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#normalizeUrl-detail) which in the docs clearly states : _If the input parameter is an array, it is treated as a controller route and a list of GET parameters, and the CController::createUrl method will be invoked to create a URL. In this case, the first array element refers to the controller route, and the rest key-value pairs refer to the additional GET parameters for the URL. For example, array('post/list', 'page'=>3) may be used to generate the URL /index.php?r=post/list&page=3._

Comment: Ah, I missed that there wasn't a closing parantheses.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like [`CHtml::ajaxLink`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail) takes more parameters than you're sending.

```
public static string ajaxLink(string $text, mixed $url, array $ajaxOptions=array ( ), array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

Do you need to send along some `$text` before the `$url`?

Comment: You are right about that, when posting my code I left that out but edited it in now.  Regardless that is not the problem here.

Comment: this is not the problem, the last 2 parameters in `CHtml::ajaxLink` are optional